# Installing a package using Android viewClient

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am trying to implement Androidviewclient to run viewbased scripts , is there any way i can install new packages using androidviewclient like the way we can with monkeyrunner using "device.installPackage()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) version **11.0.7** implements `ViewClient.installPackage()` and also introduces a new command line option `--install-apk` that generates a test precondition based on the result of the installation of the APK. See https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Test-Cookbook#installing-apks-as-preconditions for details.

`installPackage` has not been implemented in `AdbClient` because it can be replaced by `subprocess`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2014  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2015-11-14 by Culebra v10.8.2
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os
import subprocess


try:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

_s = 5
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)

apk="/path/to/my/app-debug.apk"
subprocess.check_call([vc.adb, "install", "-r", apk], shell=False)
```